# Realm model migration strategy

Tags: realm

I have run into a problem working with Realm migration blocks and the strategy for migrating realms.

Given an object MyObject with a number of properties:

- In version 1 we have the property myProperty
- In version 2 we change the property to myPropertyMk2
- In version 3 we change the property to myPropertyMk3

Given following migration block:

```
    private class func getMigrationBlock(realmPath: String) -> RLMMigrationBlock {
    return { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion == RLMNotVersioned) {
            NSLog("No database found when migrating.")
            return
        } else {
            NSLog("Migrating \(realmPath) from version \(oldSchemaVersion) to \(RealmMigrationHelper.CURRENT_DATABASE_VERSION)")
        }

        NSLog("Upgrading MyObject from version %d to %d", oldSchemaVersion, CURRENT_DATABASE_VERSION)
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
            migration.enumerateObjects(MyObject.className(), block: {
                oldObject, newObject in
                newObject["myPropertyMk2"] = oldObject["myProperty"]
            })
        } 
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 3) {
            migration.enumerateObjects(MyObject.className(), block: {
                oldObject, newObject in
                newObject["myPropertyMk3"] = oldObject["myPropertyMk2"]
            })
        } 
        NSLog("Migration complete.")
    }
}
```

When I was version 2 of the DB this worked just fine (obviously without the **oldSchemaVersion < 3** block), but when I introduced version 3 I started getting the problems because it does not recognise the **newObject["myPropertyMk2"]** in **oldSchemaVersion < 2** block. If I change it to **newObject["myPropertyMk3"]** it works just fine.

From reading the RLMMigration code this makes perfectly good sense as we work with the old schme and the new scheme, but based on the documentation on realm.io I do not think it makes sense. Then I would have expected it to be scheme less.

I have an idea about making a scheme less migration within the block by simply using a dictionary and then finally apply this dictionary to the **newObject**.

Are there any thoughts on the migration strategy of realms that deals with this? It is mentioned on realms website, but only very briefly.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your question and report of your issue.

> From reading the RLMMigration code this makes perfectly good sense as we work with the old schme and the new scheme, but based on the documentation on realm.io I do not think it makes sense. Then I would have expected it to be scheme less.

As you correctly recognized from the code in `RLMMigration`, migrations are not scheme-free. The migration closure which you provide should handle migrations **from any version in the past to the current version**. If your user didn't update your app in between and so skipped one version, there is no chance, that Realm could been aware of your intermediate schema version, as the schema is reflected at runtime. You're generally free to break the backwards-compatibility with existing old versions deliberately, but you would need to take care to reset the configuration to a defined state.

You're for sure right about the point, that this could been better documented. I have created an internal ticket about that.

> I have an idea about making a scheme less migration within the block by simply using a dictionary and then finally apply this dictionary to the newObject.
>
> Are there any thoughts on the migration strategy of realms that deals with this? It is mentioned on realms website, but only very briefly.

Depending on your scheme and the amount of data you have, you can reorganize it object-wise in memory via a dictionary and then apply it to newObject as you describe. The current API makes relatively few assumptions and allows an approach like this. But it wouldn't work in that way good for everyone, e.g. if you have large lists of related objects.

Comment: Thanks @marius - this was kind off the answer I expected but hoped for a different one :)

I am not sure which is the better approach for doing this migration of data. For now I have solved the problem by migrating from each specific object version to the current one for this given object type as it actually makes sense in this case.

Maybe doing like this pseudo code:
  migration.enumerateObjects(ChatMessageDao.className(), block: { oldObject, newObject in
     let myTempDictionary = content of oldObject
     transformValues(myTempDictionary)
     newObject = content of myTempDictionary
  }